# The latest version of Pyswmm has an error

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, conda, spyder

I am working on an optimization process through which I need some data using Pyswmm output model such as flood depths and pollutants mass.
It is only possible with latest version of pyswmm to get output data.
When I install pyswmm latest version I face this error.

(ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _solver: The specified module could not be found.)

I already looked for some suggestions regarding system environment and path changes but it did not work.
I hope anyone help me with this.

Comment: not enough info (tell us about the environment, document exactly the installation commands and the steps that lead to the error); often DLL error comes from [mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels)

Answer (score 2):

PySWMM is now updated to v1.2 which resolved this error. Sorry about it! And sorry for the delay here.  I never thought to check S.O. until today!

Check out pypi https://pypi.org/project/pyswmm/